# Twig - is it possible to use multi-word array indexes?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony 2.4.3 and the [MZMailChimpBundle](https://github.com/miguel250/MZMailChimpBundle).  It's `list()` method, which exports mailing list subscribers, does so by creating an array with the following structure:

```
array =>
    [0] =>
        [Email Address] => 'some string',
        [First Name] => 'some string',
        [Last Name] => 'some string,
        .
        .
        .
    [1] =>
        [Email Address] => 'some string',
        .
        .
        .
```

What I need to do is iterate over the list to grab that data, but I can't simply go:

```
{% for member in members %}
    {{ member.Email Addresss }}
```

So, how would I grab those multi-word array keys in a twig template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple - just address those items as you would in php:

```
{% for member in members %}
    {{ member['Email Address'] }}
```